# Can we classify continua of $\mathbb{R}^2$ transformed under homeomorphsisms and bi-measurable maps?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, continuum-theory

**Definition**. If there exists a sequence of Borel measurable sets $X_1, ..., X_n\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with positive Lebesgue measure and maps $f_i:X_i\to X_{i+1}$ such that each $f_i$ is either a homeomorphism or a bi-measurable measure preserving bijection then say that $X_1$ and $X_n$ are equivalent, denoting it by $X_1\sim X_n$.

**Question**: Can we classify compact connected subspaces with positive Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^2$ under this notion of equivalence?

**Source**: Me. Since classification of such spaces topologically seems impossible in general, I introduced measure.